# ElasticSearch not updating

Tags: php, elasticsearch

We're currently in the process of implementing ElasticSearch in our webapp. We're doing this by using the official [elasticsearch-php framework](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php). We've implemented this straight into a model to test things out, since it's new for all of us.

```
public function afterSave()
{
    $client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
    $params = [
        'index' => 'testindex',
        'type' => 'user',
        'id' => $this->id,
        'body' => [
            'id' => $this->id, 
            'name' => $this->firstname.' '.$this->lastname, 
            'email' => $this->email, 
            'test' => ''
        ]
    ];

    $response = $client->index($params);
}

public function afterUpdate()
{
    $client     =   \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
    $params     =   [
        'index' => 'testindex',
        'type' => 'user',
        'id' => $this->id
    ];

    $params['body']['doc']  =   [
        'test' => 'test2'
    ];

    $response = $client->update($params);
    var_dump($client->update($params));
    var_dump($response);
}
```

When I save the model it automatically adds it to ES, however when I update it it doesn't update the model. When I `var_dump()` the response, it doesn't throw any errors.

```
array(4) { ["index"]=> string(11) "testindex" ["type"]=> string(5) "user" ["id"]=> string(5) "20604" ["body"]=> array(1) { ["doc"]=> array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) "test2" } } } 

array(4) { ["_index"]=> string(11) "testindex" ["_type"]=> string(5) "user" ["_id"]=> string(5) "20604" ["_version"]=> int(2) } 

array(4) { ["_index"]=> string(11) "testindex" ["_type"]=> string(5) "user" ["_id"]=> string(5) "20604" ["_version"]=> int(3) }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `_version` is properly incremented on each update, it seems, which means the update worked. What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/testindex/user/20604` ?

Comment: The same, incorrect, output. `{"_index":"testindex","_type":"user","_id":"20604","_version":4,"found":true,"_source":{"id":"20604","name":"test person","email":"testperson@myemail.com","test":""}}`

Comment: If you run the curl I gave you from you shell, you should simply get the document with id `20604`, please share it.

Comment: I hit enter too early, I just shared it.

Comment: Do you use Phalcon?

Comment: Yes, we use Phalcon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Phalcon, this might be caused by `update()` calling both `afterUpdate()` and `afterSave()`. You should place a couple of `echo`'s in the `afterSave()` method; if you see them twice this is the problem.

You can prevent this behaviour by making your `afterSave()` handle updates and `afterCreate()` handle creates. You can then created models by calling `$model->create()` and update them by calling `$model->save()`.

More information about this behaviour can be found at: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#create-update-with-confidence